# Delphi Mocks with DUnitX Setup and TearDown

Tags: delphi

I am working through the Coding Delphi book, and am running into trouble with using Delphi Mocks. When I create the Mock using the [Setup] attribute with DUnitX, it appears as though it never get's created. When I create the Mock within the test itself it works correctly. I thought the point of having Setup and TearDown was so that you didn't have to build the same items for each test.

Below is the code for the unit test

```
unit uDollarToGalleonsConverterTest;

interface

uses
  uDollarToGalleonsConverter,
  Spring.Services.Logging,
  Delphi.Mocks,
  DUnitX.TestFramework;


type

  [TestFixture]
  TDollarToGalleonConverterTest = class
  private
    Expected, Actual: Double;
    Converter: TDollarsToGalleonsConverter;
    Logger: ILogger;
    [Setup]
    procedure Setup;
    [TearDown]
    procedure TearDown;
  public
    [Test]
    procedure TestPointFiveCutsDollarsInHalf;
  end;


implementation

{ TDollarToGalleonConverterTest }

procedure TDollarToGalleonConverterTest.Setup;
begin
  Logger := TMock<ILogger>.Create;
  Converter := TDollarsToGalleonsConverter.Create(Logger);
end;

procedure TDollarToGalleonConverterTest.TearDown;
begin
  Converter.Free;
end;

procedure TDollarToGalleonConverterTest.TestPointFiveCutsDollarsInHalf;
begin
  Expected := 1.0;

  Actual := Converter.ConvertDollarsToGalleons(2, 0.5);

  Assert.AreEqual(Expected, Actual,
    'Converter failed to convert 2 dollars to 1 galleon');
end;

initialization
  TDUnitX.RegisterTestFixture(TDollarToGalleonConverterTest);

end.
```

Comment: If there is an error in my book, I'd love to know about it at nickhodges@gmail.com

Comment: I don't think it's an error in your book, more of a misunderstanding on my part. I am trying to create a mock in the Setup procedure of the DUnitX testing. It works fine, when I create the mock within the test itself, as you do in the book, but if I try and do the creation in the setup, then it throws exceptions, because the mock is never created.

Answer (score 5):

By default rtti for methods is generated for public and published methods. If you have any private or protected methods the framework will not find these even if they have the attributes.

So your Setup method will never be called.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but still worth answering.

The problem is that TMock is a record, and you do not have a variable to hold it. Change Logger to TMock and it should work fine.

Edit : Forgot to mention, TMock has an implicit operator that will implement ILogger, so you can still use Logger where an ILogger is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there appears to be a mismatch between the book and reality:

Try moving your attributed methods to the public section.

Comment: I moved the methods into the public section, but I still get an exception from the Mock not getting created.

Comment: I'm stumped then. I basically do what you do here with XE5 with no problems, except I don't use a mock yet. Does Setup not get hit at all?

Comment: When I run the same setup for testing without a mock, it works properly as a private method. But once I tried using the mock, it does not create the mock.